# Dynamically pull dojo combo box options from rest api

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

I'm looking to dynamically populate a dojo combobox with values that come from a json rest api. Ideally, the user inputs their string into the combo box, a 'get' call is made returning related strings, and the select options are populated with these results.

The [JsonRest store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) seems like a good way to go about doing this, but so far my attempts have been unsuccessful. I am encountering two issues:

1. My rest api returns a list of strings, while the combo button is expecting a list of objects with specified keys to use as the names/values. I don't have access to the api so I can't change the response structure. -**Fixed**
2. The 'get' calls that the json rest store is making is adding an asterisk on to the end of the query, which isn't desirable. -**Fixed**

My setup looks like this:

```
this.testStore = new JsonRestStore({
            target: "myUrl",
            allowNoTrailingSlash: true
});

this.dapComboBox.set('store', this.testStore);
this.dapComboBox.set('searchAttr', 'tag');
```

### Update 1

I've figured out the asterisk issue, it was fixed by setting the combo box's 'queryExpr' attribute to '${0}'

### Update 2

I solved the unusable list issue by creating my own basic store with get, getIdentity, and query functions.  In my new query function I returned a new deferred object. I processed the returned values from the get request to fit the proper format and resolved this new list with my new deferred.

Comment: So if I read correctly, your question has been answered?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Fixed by setting the combo box's 'queryExpr' attribute to '${0}'

**Issue 2:** Created my own basic store with get, getIdentity, and query functions to fix. In my new query function I returned a new deferred object. I processed the returned values from the get request to fit the proper format and resolved this new list with my new deferred.